# Conditional string building

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

Essentially I'm taking a number of checkboxes off of my view, adding them to a `Dictionary<string, bool>`, and writing out the `Keys` of any checkbox that is checked.

I'm guessing there must be a better way of doing this.

```
// We need to build a list of what the user would like more information on.

// First step is to add all of the Checkboxes to a `Dictionary<string, bool>`
Dictionary<string,bool> moreInfo = new Dictionary<string,bool>();
moreInfo.Add("Children's Programs", ccm.moreInfoChildren);
moreInfo.Add("Youth Programs",ccm.moreInfoYouth);
moreInfo.Add("Small Groups", ccm.moreInfoSmallGroups);
moreInfo.Add("Getting involved in Ministry",ccm.moreInfoMinistry);
moreInfo.Add("Receiving offering envelopes",ccm.moreInfoOfferingEnvelopes);
moreInfo.Add("Church Membership",ccm.moreInfoMembership);
moreInfo.Add("Baptism",ccm.moreInfoBaptism);
moreInfo.Add("Other (see notes)", ccm.moreInfoOther);


// Second step is to loop through the moreInfo `Dictionary<string, bool>` and build a string of results.
StringBuilder _moreInfo = new StringBuilder();
foreach (var info in moreInfo) {
    _moreInfo.Append(info.Value ? info.Key + ", " : "");
}

// Third step is to determin if the user wants any information. If they do, we add that information to the email.
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_moreInfo.ToString()))
{
    builder.Append("I would like more information about ");
    builder.Append(_moreInfo.ToString());
}
```

Here is the complete `Action`:

```
[HttpGet]
[AllowCrossSiteJsonAttribute]
public JsonpResult CommunicateCard(CommunicateCardModel ccm)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

        // ccm.name is a required field, so we don't have to check if it's empty.
        builder.Append("Name: " + ccm.name + "\n");

        // If these properties are empty, we don't want to include them in the built string.
        builder.Append((!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ccm.address)) ? "Address: " + ccm.address + "\n" : null);
        builder.Append((!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ccm.city)) ? "City: " + ccm.city + "\n" : null);
        builder.Append((!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ccm.postalCode)) ? "Postal Code: " + ccm.postalCode + "\n" : null);
        builder.Append((!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ccm.phone)) ? "Phone Number: " + ccm.phone + "\n" : null);
        builder.Append((!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ccm.emailFrom)) ? "Email Address: " + ccm.emailFrom + "\n" : null);

        builder.Append("\n");

        builder.Append((!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ccm.information)) ? "Please " + ccm.information + "\n" : null);
        builder.Append((!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ccm.christianity)) ? "I " + ccm.christianity + "\n" : null);
        builder.Append((!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ccm.maritalStatus)) ? "I am " + ccm.maritalStatus + "\n" : null);

        builder.Append("\n");


        // pull together all of the checkboxes within the "Ministries" fieldset and generate a single string.
        var pairs = new[]
        {
            // Tuple.Create(string, bool)
            Tuple.Create("Children's Programs", ccm.moreInfoChildren),
            Tuple.Create("Youth Programs", ccm.moreInfoYouth),
            Tuple.Create("Small Groups", ccm.moreInfoSmallGroups),
            Tuple.Create("Getting involved in Ministry", ccm.moreInfoMinistry),
            Tuple.Create("Receiving offering envelopes", ccm.moreInfoOfferingEnvelopes),
            Tuple.Create("Church Membership", ccm.moreInfoMembership),
            Tuple.Create("Baptism", ccm.moreInfoBaptism),
            Tuple.Create("Other (see notes)", ccm.moreInfoOther),
        };

        var moreInfo = String.Join(", ", pairs.Where(pair => pair.Item2).Select(pair => pair.Item1));

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(moreInfo))
        {
            builder.Append("I would like more information about ")
                   .Append(moreInfo);
        }

        builder.Append("\n");

        builder.Append((!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ccm.guestReason)) ? "I am visiting today because " + ccm.guestReason + "\n" : null);
        builder.Append((!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ccm.attendance)) ? "I am attending for my " + ccm.attendance + "\n" : null);

        builder.Append("\n");

        builder.Append((!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ccm.comments)) ?  ccm.comments : null);


        // initiate the email service and fire off an email
        EmailService email = new EmailService();
        email.to = ccm.emailTo;
        email.from = ccm.emailTo;
        email.replyTo = ccm.emailFrom;
        email.subject = ccm.messageSubject;
        email.messageBody = builder.ToString();

        bool sent = email.send();
        object result = null;

        // Send a system error message via JSON back to the app if the email fails.
        if (!sent)
        {
            result = new ErrorsModel { ErrorMessage = Server.GetLastError().Message };
        }

        // whether or not the email sent, we need to tell the app the result.
        return this.Jsonp(result, sent);
    }
    // The ModelState is invalid, Loop through the ModelState and send a JSON string listing all the errors.
    else 
    {
        List<ErrorsModel> Errors = new List<ErrorsModel>();
        foreach(ModelState modelState in ModelState.Values)
        {
            foreach (ModelError error in modelState.Errors)
            {
                Errors.Add(new ErrorsModel { ErrorMessage = error.ErrorMessage });
            };
        };

        return this.Jsonp(Errors, false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your method has a lot of repetition to build your string often resulting in unnecessary calls to `Append()`.  You should have used an `if` block for each of those writes instead of appending `null`.  This also hides all the calls to `IsNullOrEmpty()` which is a detail you don't really want repeated so much.  I'd break this into a couple of methods, one for each of the valid/invalid cases and one to help with writing the strings.  Written this way, you have the option to use the same trick to quickly build the comma-separated list to write your content easier to do.  I think you'll agree that it's a lot more easier to read.

```
[HttpGet]
[AllowCrossSiteJsonAttribute]
public JsonpResult CommunicateCard(CommunicateCardModel ccm)
{
    return ModelState.IsValid
        ? CommunicateValidCard(ccm)
        : CommunicateInvalidCard(ccm);
}

StringBuilder AppendNonWhiteField(StringBuilder builder, string format, string field)
{
    if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(field))
    {
        builder.AppendFormat(format, field);
    }
    return builder;
}

JsonpResult CommunicateValidCard(CommunicateCardModel ccm)
{
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

    // ccm.name is a required field, so we don't have to check if it's empty.
    builder.Append("Name: " + ccm.name + "\n");

    // If these properties are empty, we don't want to include them in the built string.
    AppendNonWhiteField(builder, "Address: {0}\n",       ccm.address);
    AppendNonWhiteField(builder, "City: {0}\n",          ccm.city);
    AppendNonWhiteField(builder, "Postal Code: {0}\n",   ccm.postalCode);
    AppendNonWhiteField(builder, "Phone Number: {0}\n",  ccm.phone);
    AppendNonWhiteField(builder, "Email Address: {0}\n", ccm.emailFrom);
    builder.AppendLine();

    AppendNonWhiteField(builder, "Please {0}\n", ccm.information);
    AppendNonWhiteField(builder, "I {0}\n",      ccm.christianity);
    AppendNonWhiteField(builder, "I am {0}\n",   ccm.maritalStatus);
    builder.AppendLine();

    // pull together all of the checkboxes within the "Ministries" fieldset and generate a single string.
    var pairs = new[]
    {
        // Tuple.Create(string, bool)
        Tuple.Create("Children's Programs",          ccm.moreInfoChildren),
        Tuple.Create("Youth Programs",               ccm.moreInfoYouth),
        Tuple.Create("Small Groups",                 ccm.moreInfoSmallGroups),
        Tuple.Create("Getting involved in Ministry", ccm.moreInfoMinistry),
        Tuple.Create("Receiving offering envelopes", ccm.moreInfoOfferingEnvelopes),
        Tuple.Create("Church Membership",            ccm.moreInfoMembership),
        Tuple.Create("Baptism",                      ccm.moreInfoBaptism),
        Tuple.Create("Other (see notes)",            ccm.moreInfoOther),
    };
    var moreInfo = String.Join(", ", pairs.Where(pair => pair.Item2).Select(pair => pair.Item1));
    AppendNonWhiteField(builder, "I would like more information about {0}\n", moreInfo);

    AppendNonWhiteField(builder, "I am visiting today because {0}\n", ccm.guestReason);
    AppendNonWhiteField(builder, "I am attending for my {0}\n",       ccm.attendance);
    builder.AppendLine();

    AppendNonWhiteField(builder, "{0}", ccm.comments);

    // initiate the email service and fire off an email
    EmailService email = new EmailService();
    email.to = ccm.emailTo;
    email.from = ccm.emailTo;
    email.replyTo = ccm.emailFrom;
    email.subject = ccm.messageSubject;
    email.messageBody = builder.ToString();

    bool sent = email.send();
    object result = null;

    // Send a system error message via JSON back to the app if the email fails.
    if (!sent)
    {
        result = new ErrorsModel { ErrorMessage = Server.GetLastError().Message };
    }

    // whether or not the email sent, we need to tell the app the result.
    return this.Jsonp(result, sent);
}

JsonpResult CommunicateInvalidCard(CommunicateCardModel ccm)
{
    // The ModelState is invalid, Loop through the ModelState and send a JSON string listing all the errors.
    var errors = ModelState.Values
        .SelectMany(modelState =>
            modelState.Errors
                .Select(error => new ErrorsModel { ErrorMessage = error.ErrorMessage }))
        .ToList();
    return this.Jsonp(errors, false);
}
```

Comment: There's no value in using a string builder for a single concatenation like this, use String.Concat or just the + (which overloads to String.Concat, so it's just a style difference). StringBuilder is for when you're going to append in a loop an unknown but plausibly significant number of strings.

Comment: @Jimmy: Of course, but it was clear to me that this snippet of code wasn't fully complete.  This could have (and was) a small part of a larger method where using the builder was relevant.  Within this snippet alone, the builder definitely wouldn't have been necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing if you need the dictionary for later use, you can absolutely make the 2nd step better (and remove the trailing ", " that would get added) by using String.Join with a lambda (don't forget to add the System.Linq using if it is not there):

```
// Second step is to loop through the moreInfo `Dictionary<string, bool>` and build a string of results.
string _moreInfo = String.Join(", ", moreInfo.Where(m => m.Value).Select(m => m.Key).ToArray());
```

Then you can also drop the .ToString() on the IsNullOrEmpty check of _moreInfo and the append of _moreInfo in step 3.